# Open an activity from a button inside a fragment (SOLVED!)

Tags: javascript, android

Hey i'm really new with coding, i'm trying to open an activity from a button inside a fragment (this fragment is from the navigation drawer activity) but i literally can't. Whenever i try to open my app it crashes, so i did some research and saw the way to do it. The problem is, idk where to place the solution in my code. I've been trying to put it inside the fragment (everywhere, but doesn't work), so it opens the activity once its' button is clicked. Here is my coding, but this attempt crashes every time I click on my fragment inside the app. The coding inside the ServicosFragment constructor is the one idk where to put, because everywhere else it gives me different errors in the coding, this is the only place i can make the coding right and just crash the app. Can anyone help?

```js
public class ServicosFragment extends Fragment {

    public  ServicosFragment (){
        Button buttonCriacaoeGestao = getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonCriacaoeGestao);
        buttonCriacaoeGestao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CriacaoeGestaoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicos, container, false);


        }


}
```

Comment: why don't you post the logcat error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the view before inflating the view, That's should be crashing your app.

Here you are trying to register a click listener on a Button on the constructer. But when the constructor is running the view hasn't inflated yet, so you can not access something not there, Instead, move the code to the onViewCreated method as follows.

And also remove the return keyword before inflater otherwise the method will terminate before setting the button on click listener.

**EDIT - ** I'm really sorry I just have ignored that I have to return a view in onCreateView method in a fragment( Unlike in onCreate method in an activity ). So here I have edit the answer, This must work. You save the view in a View object and you finally need to return it at the end of the method.

And also you can access buttons and other components in your xml through the view as shown in the code.

```
public class ServicosFragment extends Fragment {

public  ServicosFragment (){



}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicos, container, false);

    Button buttonCriacaoeGestao = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCriacaoeGestao);
    buttonCriacaoeGestao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CriacaoeGestaoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for answering. I tried this code just like it is here and i got an error on the second to last "}", it says it is missing a return statement. I tried typing `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicos, container, false);`and returning the view at the end, but it also didn't work. Another thing i tried to do was just move the code from inside of the constructor to the place you suggested, but i got an error at `Button buttonCriacaoeGestao = getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonCriacaoeGestao);´saying that the entire thing was an unreachable statement.Any idea?

Comment: instead of using the getView().findViewById() use view.findViewById() as now you can access your view object, and I change the code in the answer as well. Let me know if this didn't work out, and also attached the stack trace.

Comment: It worked!! I literally can't thank you enough. The code not working was really bugging me and i was very disappointed with myself. Again, thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: You are welcome , try to include the stacktrace when you asking about a error next time

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the constructor. Your constructor tries to open new activity before your fragment gets it view. Please try it like this without any constructors.

```
public class ServicosFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         Button buttonCriacaoeGestao=getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonCriacaoeGestao);
         buttonCriacaoeGestao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CriacaoeGestaoActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }});

         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicos, container, false);     
    }
}
```

And when you ask a question next time, please try to provide what exceptions your app gets when it crashes.

Comment: thank you for the answer! i tried inserting the code but it unfortunately crashes as soon as i click on the fragment, the app just suddenly closes and doesn't say anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps

```
public class ServicosFragment extends Fragment {
    Button buttonCriacaoeGestao;
    public  ServicosFragment (){

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        buttonCriacaoeGestao = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCriacaoeGestao);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    buttonCriacaoeGestao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CriacaoeGestaoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicos, container, false);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the answer! Unfortunately the app still has the same problem, as soon as i try clicking on the fragment it just closes the app :( maybe i'm doing something wrong on other part of the app, i'll proof read everything again

Comment: The thing is it is difficult to know what is happening without seeying what error you are getting. Can you paste the stacktrace?